# How to click the nearest link

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Lets say we have a table of people. In each row there is a picture, a name, a city and some social buttons, like PM, add as friend, follow.

How can I "Add as friend" a certain person?
There are 10 people, there are 10 "Add as friend" buttons, and I have a name - lets say George Busch.

I don't know which place is his profile going to take out of those 10, when the page is generated, I just want to click the  "add as friend" link that is NEAREST to George Busch.

EDIT: I will use the example code provided from the accepted answer, to demonstrate my case:

```
<table id="addfriendstable" class="colouredgrid">
    <tr id="person65894" class="resultsrow odd">
        <td>George Busch</td>
        <td><button class="befriend">Add as friend</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="person3244" class="resultsrow even">
        <td>Jimmy Corker</td>
        <td><button class="befriend">Add as friend</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="person91236" class="resultsrow odd">
        <td>Abraham Linton</td>
        <td><button class="befriend">Add as friend</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: This is my real-life example. I can't connect the xpaths right

These are the user's clickable name xpaths:

```
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Justin Timberlake')])[2]

//div[@id='main']/div/section/section/ul/li[2]/article/section/section/a

xpath=(//a[contains(@href, '/users/justin-timberlake')])[4]

//li[2]/article/section/section/a
```

and these are the different variants of the "Add as friend" button:

```
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Add as Friend')])[2]

//div[@id='main']/div/section/section/ul/li[2]/article/section/section/div/a

//a[contains(@href, '/users/1/friendships?friend_id=51c027d7f325db7ee7000032&origin=search')]

//li[2]/article/section/section/div/a
```

Comment: Well, I was talking generally, but tomorrow at work I will try to simulate this situation and show some code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an xpath which identifies the table cell containing the text 'George Busch', and then tracks over to the cell containing the button. This is concise and efficient.

Exactly how the xpath is constructed depends on your overall html structure, but I'll show you a simple worked example.

#### HTML

```html
<table id="addfriendstable" class="colouredgrid">
    <tr id="person65894" class="resultsrow odd">
        <td>George Busch</td>
        <td><button class="befriend">Add as friend</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="person3244" class="resultsrow even">
        <td>Jimmy Corker</td>
        <td><button class="befriend">Add as friend</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="person91236" class="resultsrow odd">
        <td>Abraham Linton</td>
        <td><button class="befriend">Add as friend</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Building the xpath

The first part of the xpath is to uniquely identify the `td` cell with your text in it. For now, I'm assuming that you know for certain that the person's name won't show up anywhere else in the screen's html:

```xml
//td[text()='George Busch']
```

The next part of the xpath uses the double-dot `..` notation to represent the parent, because we want to go back up the hierarchy one level to the `tr` table row:

```xml
//td[text()='George Busch']/..
```

And the next part of the xpath goes down the hierarchy a level to find the button; for now, I'm assuming that each row of the table has only one button:

```xml
//td[text()='George Busch']/../td/button
```

So the overall pattern is concentrating on two elements, the person name and the button; the xpath finds the person name first, then tracks back up the hierarchy as far as the common parent, then back down to the button.

#### Tweaking the xpath

Depending on your overall html structure, my example xpath might need changing. For example, maybe the screen has a number of different tables where the text '*George Busch*' might occur? In that case, you need to uniquely identify the table, for example by using the id like this:

```xml
//table[@id='addfriendstable']//td[text()='George Busch']/../td/button
```

Or maybe the table has several buttons in each row? If so, we need to uniquely identify which button we want, for example by using the class:

```xml
//td[text()='George Busch']/../td/button[@class='befriend']
```

#### Firepath

I really recommend using [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) for firefox - it's a great tool for checking that your xpaths are working. I've used it to verify the example xpaths in this answer.

Comment: this is an amazing explanation!!!! The only thing about firepath is that it only gives me one variant of the xpath, so I use selenium ide, and I click on the element I want, then go to the editor and from the dropdown menu, I get different variants of the same xpath, so I use the one that I want, here is an example:

xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Justin Timberlake')])[2] or
//div[@id='main']/div/section/section/ul/li[2]/article/section/section/a or xpath=(//a[contains(@href, '/users/justin-timberlake')])[4]

Comment: Instead of using the dots which again specifies position we can use two forward slash // This would negate any changes in the html structure as well.

Comment: I've edited my answer, providing my real-life example. Can you show me how to connect the xpaths?

Comment: The xpath is //tr[td[text() = 'Abraham Linton']]/descendant::td/button[text() = 'Add as friend']

Comment: @JennyKowalski You can never trust the xpaths suggested by any tool, I'm afraid; they're always too fragile - e.g. they'll assume that you're looking for the cell in the 3rd row down, something like that. You really have to construct your xpaths yourself from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a very common scenario when comes to working with grids. The best way to do this is by using xpath. The trick is to get the row which contains the name George Busch no matter where the row is in the grid. In the row click on the button. Will give a simple example using the grid in the following website.
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html 
.The grid customer database there are many users. I will show the xpath which will get the age for person with first name Margaret. If you show the html probably something similar to this can be given. The xpath is as follows.

```
//tr[td[text() = 'Margaret']]/descendant::td[text()= '55']
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a selector so that a `findElements()` will return 10 elements (one for each person)

On each element, do a `element.getText()`, and test to see if it contains George Busch.

If it does, then on the next element, do a `element.findElement("")` selector that will return the link, and click on it.

Comment: will try it tomorrow and share the results

Comment: do I do the findElements() for the usernames or for the "add as friend" buttons or for the tables? @MrTi